# horizontally slidable launcher android

Tags: android, launcher

I got launcher2 code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/launcher2/source/checkout). It works fine but the allapps screen scrolls vertically when there are more number of apps than the number that fits in ones screen . But launcher2 code present in the ICS source has the all apps screens which scrlls horizontally . I would like to which files I need to edit so that i can get this effect .

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a ViewPager. You can refer the official docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: thanks for your help . but how I tried viewpager & it works fine except for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580591/viewpager-does-not-slide-in-the-middle-of-screen-android . I was thinking there must be any easy way of editing the laucher2 code